# allow users to move items that don't equal to the value stated in a function

Tags: javascript

I have searched google and unable to find the logic for what I am trying to achieve, the easiest way I am able to explain this over text is with an example let's say you have 5 apples and you say to the 'move box you want to move 6 apples but instead of the 'move box' throwing an error because the amount of items you want to move doesn't equal in the value (6) in the 'movebox' it takes all 5 items and disregards the extra value that's left another example you have 10 apples you put into the move box you want to move 4, and instead of the move box throwing an error because the value doesn't match it will just take 4 apples and leave 6. right now if I want to move an item i have to make sure that I have the same amount of item that I enter into the move box like if I want to move 7 and I have 6 I will not move them becasue the item value doesn't match the move box value, if you me need to explain more I am happy to do so.

right now the block of code that deals with the number of items that will be moved is

```js
if ($(this).val() == "") {
            $(this).val("1")
```

with the default move value set at 1, I haven't tried anything except search through google because I simply don't know the logic for the problem I'm facing.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#count").focus(function () {
        $(this).val("")
    }).blur(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == "") {
            $(this).val("1")
        }
    });
```

Comment: so, what that entity you have to move exactly is ? I mean is it some arrays content or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Limit the move count to the number of apples using `Math.min()`.

```
var move_count = parseInt($(this).val()) || 1;
move_count = Math.min(move_count, number_of_apples);
number_of_apples -= move_count;
```

or subtract the move count and then set the number of apples to zero if it's below zero.

```
var move_count = parseInt($(this).val()) || 1;
number_of_apples -= move_count;
if (number_of_apples < 0) {
  number_of_apples = 0;
}
```